# Compare multiple Python lists and merge on Levenshtein similarity

Tags: python, list, function, compare, levenshtein-distance

I have written a Python function that takes two lists, compares them using Levenshtein and merges words that are similar enough, into a list called '*merged*'.

How can I do this for 6+ lists? Making sure that each list is compared to the 5 other lists and so on?

```py
first_list = ["Mouse", "Cat", "Dog", "Gremlinge", "Horse"]
second_list = ["Mouse", "Cat", "Hors", "Dog", "Gremling"]
third_list = ["Mouse", "Cat", "Horrs", "Dog", "Greemling"]
fourth_list = ["Mouse", "Cate", "Dog", "Gremlinge", "Horse"]
fifth_list = ["Mose", "Cat", "Hors", "Dog", "Gremling"]
sixth_list = ["Mouse", "Cat", "Horser", "Doeg", "Gremling"]

def lev_merging(a, b): # function to compare 2 lists
  merged = [] # Empty list to add the matching words
  for first in a:
    for second in b:
      if levenshtein(first, second) < 2:
        merged.append(set([first,second]))
  return merged

print (lev_merging(first_list,second_list))
```

[Working www.repl.it fiddle of code.](https://repl.it/GJOH/1)

Comment: So you want to compare every word in `first_list` to every word in `second_list`?

Comment: Thank you for your comment. No, that is what my function does currently. I have updated the post to show the other 4 lists, that I want my function to also go through and merge on similarity.

Comment: Could you give a sample output you are looking for? Are you looking for the result to be a single list where each element in the list is a set of all the "close" words from all of the lists.  So `[{"Mouse","Mose"}, {"Cat", "Cate"}, ...]`

Comment: Yes, thank you, that is exactly what I am looking for. Preferably I would also like to only merge the "close" words, and into their own list, if they come from 3 or more lists, which would need some sort of counter, I imagine?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We'll have a list of lists of strings

```
list_of_lists = [["Mouse", "Cat", "Dog", "Gremlinge", "Horse"],
                  ["Mouse", "Cat", "Hors", "Dog", "Gremling"],
                  ["Mouse", "Cat", "Horrs", "Dog", "Greemling"],
                  ["Mouse", "Cate", "Dog", "Gremlinge", "Horse"],
                  ["Mose", "Cat", "Hors", "Dog", "Gremling"],
                  ["Mouse", "Cat", "Horser", "Doeg", "Gremling"]]
```

Then we'll iterate through this list, keeping track of the index of the list we are "in", and compare this list to all the lists that come after it.

```
def merging(list_of_lists):
    merged = []
    for i, a in enumerate(list_of_lists):
        for b in list_of_lists[i+1:]:
            for first in a:
                for second in b:
                    if lev(first, second) < 2:
                        merged.append((first, second))
    return merged
```

EDIT: The below code passes pairs of lists into a function, and separates them into groups.  Then we will process each of those groups into sets, to remove duplicates.

```
target_num_words = 6
target_num_words

def merging(list_of_lists):
    groups = []
    for i, a in enumerate(list_of_lists):
        for b in list_of_lists[i+1:]:
            if number_of_matches(a, b) >= target_num_words:
                for g in groups:
                    if a in g or b in g:
                        g.append(a if b in g else b)
                        break
                else:
                    groups.append([a, b])
    merged = []
    for g in groups:
        if len(g) >= target_num_lists:
            merged.append({x for l in g for x in l})
    return merged
```

`number_of_matches` is basically your Levenshtein code, except it just returns that number of matching words there are between two lists.  Even if this isn't exactly what you want, this should give you some idea of how to get there.

Comment: This is truly wonderful and just what I am looking for! Would it however be possible, somehow to group up the words that are similar and exclude / remove the duplicates? And would it be possible to only return merged if >3 lists had been merged?

Comment: How would you group them?  If `A` is sufficiently similar to `B` and `B` is sufficiently similar to `C`, are `A` `B` and `C` in the same group even if `A` is not similar to `C`?

Comment: Very good question. I am actually looking for a solution that will merge the lists together in separate lists depending on number of matching or 'close' words and number of lists those words come from. So imagine there are 3 lists with 6 matching animal words: `List A`, `List B`, `List C`, I'd want these merged together in `List 1`, with no duplicates. But `List D` and `List E`, with 6 matching words about something else, wouldn't be matched, being only from 2 lists. And if  `List A`, `List B`, `List C` had less than 6 matching words, they would also not be merged.

Comment: Your edit looks super and looks like what I am looking for. Though I am afraid I don't understand the if `number_of_matches(a, b) >= target_num_words:` line? How can I call a variable like that? Or am I misunderstanding something completely? Is this where you'd suggest I add and rewrite the Levenshtein script?

Comment: `number_of_matches` would be a function (that i haven't written because it's not really relevant) that takes two lists and returns the number of matches between those two lists

Comment: Wrote that myself, thank you so much for your fantastic help - I have accepted your solution as the answer.

Answer (score 1):

This answer has two solutions. For both, you need to create a list which contains all the lists you want to compare.

For example using your case above, you would do the following:

```
lists = [first_list, second_list]
```

**ITERTOOLS Solution**

In this solution you use the `itertools.combinations` method which goes through every possible combination meaning it compares each list to every other list. You would implement it like this:

```
import itertools
for a, b in itertools.combinations(lists, 2):
    for first in a:
        for second in b:
            if levenshtein(first, second) < 2:
                merged.append(first)
```

The `itertools.combinations` method takes two arguments, the first being the iterable and the second being the number of elements in each combination. In this case 2. For example:

```
itertools.combinations('ABCD', 2)
```

returns:

```
('A', 'B')
('A', 'C')
('A', 'D')
('B', 'C')
('B', 'D')
('C', 'D')
```

and:

```
itertools.combinations('ABCD', 3)
```

returns:

```
('A', 'B', 'C')
('A', 'B', 'D')
('A', 'C', 'D')
('B', 'C', 'D')
```

**FOR LOOP Solution**

If you don't feel like importing some weird modules don't worry. You can always use this solution which only requires 2 `for` loops.

```
for i in range(len(lists)):
    for j in range(i + 1, len(lists)):
        for first in lists[i]:
            for second in lists[j]:
                if levenshtein(first, second) < 2:
                    merged.append(set([first,second]))
```

By doing this you successfully compare every item in each list with every item in the other lists without ever comparing 2 lists twice.

Comment: This is also exactly what I am looking for, thank you. Are there any advantages in terms of speed, using itertools? Also, would it be possible to group the resulting list based on word-groups and eliminate duplicates? So that Horse, Horser and Hors would be group and present only once?

Comment: `Itertools` was written in C so I believe that since C is 400 times faster than Python the module should be quite a bit faster. However, I am not entirely sure.